# str_replace() does not work as expected on crypt() output

Tags: php

I'm trying to figure out how I'm going to keep a very simply encrypted value in a database.  It's nothing terribly sensitive, obviously.  But, you know how the crypt() function leaves the salt parameter in the front of the string after it has produced the encrypted string.  I'm trying to remove it using str_replace(), but it's not working.  It still has the salt parameter that I used in the original function in it.  Can anybody please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
<?php
$password=$_GET['password']; 
$salt="$2x$07$654fadkdlaf6361q4z2fs$";
$passwordCrypt=crypt($password, $salt);
echo $passwordCrypt."<br />";
$trimmed = str_replace($salt, "", $passwordCrypt);
echo $trimmed;
?>
```

Result of running the script:

```
$2x$07$654fadkdlaf6361q4z2fs.QpVju.Don9u/cEmr6utzgUPP9CrH6ua
$2x$07$654fadkdlaf6361q4z2fs.QpVju.Don9u/cEmr6utzgUPP9CrH6ua
```

Comment: When you `crypt` a password with a salt, the salt isn't actually in the crypted string.

Comment: Why does it show up when I echo it?

Comment: *"you know how the crypt() function leaves the salt parameter in the front of the string"* <- you sure about that? I see *most* of the salt as a prefix but not *all* of it, specifically the last character (from your particular salt) is not present.

Comment: You shouldn't $_GET passwords as they could be left in the browser cache and you salt should be random to every password, or else it is useless...

Comment: Arian, even when used during an ajax request?

Comment: @include'breakDance' Yes, even then. Use POST

Comment: Phil, thank you, so does that mean that most people will leave it as is when storing it in a database?  I just kind of figured that maybe people usually try to hide what hash type they use.

Comment: Thanks phil, I had no idea $_GET in ajax would still be saved in cache, good info!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problem

The reason why the str_replace() isn't working, is because you are searching for a string that doesn't exist in the other string.

Your salt is:

```
$2x$07$654fadkdlaf6361q4z2fs$
```

but it is not the same as

```
$2x$07$654fadkdlaf6361q4z2fs.QpVju.Don9u/cEmr6utzgUPP9CrH6ua
                            ^ does not have a '$' on the end
```

Your salt has an extra $ at the end of it.

### Solution

Change

```
$trimmed = str_replace($salt, "", $passwordCrypt);
```

to

```
$trimmed = str_replace("$2x$07$654fadkdlaf6361q4z2fs", "", $passwordCrypt);
```

OR you can change your salt variable to this (but as Phil pointed out, it would render your function crypt useless):

```
$salt = "$2x$07$654fadkdlaf6361q4z2fs";
```

---

### Other Problems

Unrelated to your question, but good to know is:

You shouldn't use $_GET passwords as they could be left in the browser cache and your salt should be random to every password, or else it is useless...

Good read: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17421/how-to-store-salt

Comment: Changing the salt is not an answer to this question

Comment: @Phil that is the reason why the str_replace() isn't working, because he is search for a variable that doesn't exist in the string.

Comment: Using your salt, all results of `crypt` will be `*0`. See http://codepad.viper-7.com/GtAwuW

Comment: @Phil I've updated my answer so he changes the `str_replace()` parameters... thanks for the heads up